# Linear Regression with CNN using Pytorch: input and target shapes do not match: input [400 x 1], target [200 x 1]

Tags: python, linear-regression, pytorch

Let me explain the objective first. Let's say I have 1000 images each with an associated quality score [in range of 0-10]. Now, I am trying to perform the image quality assessment using CNN with regression(in PyTorch). I have divided the images into equal size patches. Now, I have created a CNN network in order to perform the linear regression.

Following is the code:

```
class MultiLabelNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MultiLabelNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3200,1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 3200)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

While running this code of network I am getting following error

input and target shapes do not match: input [400 x 1], target [200 x 1]

the target shape is [200x1] is because I have taken the batch size of 200. I found the solution that if I change "self.fc1 = nn.Linear(3200,1024)" and "x = x.view(-1, 3200)" here from 3200 to 6400 my code runs without any error.

Similarly, It will throw an error input and target shapes do not match: input [100 x 1], target [200 x 1] if I put 12800 instead of 6400

Now my doubt is that I am not able to understand the reason behind this. If I am giving 200 images as input to my network then why the input shape is getting affected while changing the parameters when I move from convolutional layer to fully connected layer. I hope I have clearly mentioned my doubt. Even though I anybody has any doubt please ask me. It will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please tell us the line number where the first error occurs. Also, kindly give us the shape of the input which you are passing to the model in the form (batch_size x height x width x number x channels) so that we will be able to help you. This is not a serious error. We can easily sort it out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Akhilesh. My input details are as follows:

Comment: Thank you for your reply Akhilesh. My input details are as follows:
image size: 32x32x1 (i.e. single channel). Batch size does not affect the problem. Here I am taking a batch size of 200. The Problem is if my batch size is say "N" then the input and target shapes should match: input [N x 1], target [N x 1]. My problem is that I am not able to understand the significance of deciding the parameters of the very First "Fully connected layer".

Comment: Error of size mismatch is generating because of this "self.fc1 = nn.Linear("3200",1024)" parameter in double inverted quotes i.e 3200. If I am changing this parameter the input shape gets change. Reason behind it i am not able to understand

Comment: It gives the error while calculating the training Loss loss = criterion(train_outputs, train_labels.float())

Comment: you have to manually calculate the output size from each convolution layer as given here http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/. I will try to send you the exact input dimension for the fully connected layer. In the meantime, you try calculating using the formula.

Comment: Thank you Ankhilesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MultiLabelNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MultiLabelNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(6400,1024)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 1)

   def forward(self, x):
       #shape of x is (b_s, 32,32,1)
       x = self.conv1(x) #shape of x is (b_s, 28,28,132)
       x = F.relu(x)
       x = self.pool(x) #shape of x now becomes (b_s X 14 x 14 x 32)
       x = self.conv2(x) # shape(b_s, 10x10x64)
       x = F.relu(x)#size is (b_s x 10 x 10 x 64)
       x = x.view(-1, 3200) # shape of x is now(b_s*2, 3200)
       #this is the problem 
       #you can fc1 to be of shape (6400,1024) and that will work 
       x = self.fc1(x)
       x = F.relu(x)
       x = self.fc2(x)
       x = F.relu(x)
       x = self.fc3(x)
       return x
```

I think this should work. Let me know if some errors still remain.

Comment: Thank you so much, Akhilesh. I have got my answer. Please tell me what is b_s here

Comment: Welcome, @adityaraj. By b_s I mean batch_size. Did you get your program running now?